# JavaFX NullPointerException and "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception, runtimeexception, invocationtargetexception

i started learning JavaFX , and watched a tutorial.
When i click the button it shows me these errors , and i have no idea how to fix this.
Main.java

```
package employee;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {


    private Stage primaryStage ;
    private BorderPane mainLayout;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException{

        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        this.primaryStage.setTitle("Empleyee App");
        showMainView();
        showMainItems();


    }
     private void showMainView ()throws IOException
    {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/MainView.fxml"));
        mainLayout = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(mainLayout);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void showMainItems()throws IOException
    {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/MainItems.fxml"));
        BorderPane mainItems = loader.load();
        mainLayout.setCenter(mainItems);
    }



    public void showElectricalScene() throws IOException
    {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("electrical/ElectricalDep.fxml"));
        BorderPane electricalDep = loader.load();
        mainLayout.setCenter(electricalDep);
    }       

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
```

MainItemsController.java

```
  package employee.view;

import employee.Main;
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;



public class MainItemsController {

    private Main main = new Main();

    @FXML
    private void goElectrical() throws IOException
    {
       main.showElectricalScene();
    }

}
```

MainItems.fxml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane?>

<BorderPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="employee.view.MainItemsController">
   <center>
      <FlowPane hgap="20.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" vgap="20.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="electricalDepButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#goElectrical" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="120.0" text="Electrical Dep" />
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="120.0" text="Mechanical Dep" />
         </children>
         <padding>
            <Insets left="20.0" top="20.0" />
         </padding>
      </FlowPane>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

ElectricalDep.fxml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<BorderPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <top>
      <Label text="Electrical Department" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <font>
            <Font size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
   </top>
   <center>
      <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.28929765886287623" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <items>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
               <children>
                  <TableView prefHeight="371.0" prefWidth="170.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                    <columns>
                      <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Names" />
                    </columns>
                     <columnResizePolicy>
                        <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
                     </columnResizePolicy>
                  </TableView>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
               <children>
                  <TabPane layoutX="20.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="371.0" prefWidth="422.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                    <tabs>
                      <Tab text="G.Informations">
                        <content>
                          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                        </content>
                      </Tab>
                      <Tab text="Overall Data">
                        <content>
                          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                        </content>
                      </Tab>
                    </tabs>
                  </TabPane>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
        </items>
      </SplitPane>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

OUTPUT:

```
    Oct 31, 2016 4:46:02 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
    WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 8.0.65 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.25
    Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1762)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1645)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8216)
        at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
        at javafx.ev

ent.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3724)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3452)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1728)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2461)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:348)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:273)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:382)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:553)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:925)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/29531133.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1759)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at employee.Main.showElectricalScene(Main.java:64)
    at employee.view.MainItemsController.goElectrical(MainItemsController.java:26)
    ... 57 more
```

Comment: You never assign the `main` field in `MainItemsController`, which means the value remains `null`.

Comment: i assign that now:
    private void goElectrical() throws IOException
    {
        main = new Main();
       main.showElectricalScene();
    }    
now the output:
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at employee.Main.showElectricalScene(Main.java:64)
 at employee.view.MainItemsController.goElectrical(MainItemsController.java:26)
 ... 57 more